# Ruby Cucumber running multiple feature files

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I can have cucumber run all the features in a directory or a file of scenarios (like the rerun formatter). If I have two feature files in different directories, how can I execute them in a single cucumber execution? I want to execute features 1 and 3 below:

```
features
--dir1
----feature1.feature
----feature2.feature
--dir2
----feature3.feature
----feature4.feature
--dir3
----#more feature files
--dir4
----#more feature files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cucumber --require features features/dir1/feature1.feature features/dir2/feature3.feature
```

"--require features" is needed if you are using subdirectories.

After that simply list the feature files you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

I could not imagine why you would want to manage your feature testing like that. [Cuke has tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags) that allow you to categorize your feature files and scenarios within them. You can even tag Example tables (with multiple tables for one scenario outline).